# Add roman or big numbers to enumerate Headers in a Readme.md markdown file

Tags: git, github, markdown

I'm writing a `readme.md` file for the first time for a project on github, I want to enumerate the big titles (`Headers`), I tried using lists only as follows :

```
2. Select area

Drag the mouse all by clicking  on the mouse left button to select the area you want to capture from the screen.

3. Save

By releasing the mouse left button and terminating your selection, you will need to click on the save button
```

But that doesn't work really I get this :

[image]

I tried to add the listing numbers to headers , by doing :

```
### 1. Click on take a snip

Click on the left button to start snipping
```

But that doesn't really work and I get a strange formatting :

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this :

[image]

How to do that properly in Markdown, I don't want to cheat, I want to do it the right way.

Comment: Could you elaborate on : "But that doesn't really work and I get a strange formatting :" please ? I've just done some tests and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Those are screenshots , that's what I get

Comment: it's the green stuff that's making you nervous ? I think it's just a marker of what you are adding no ?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what is making me nervous, I want to have like in the 3rd screenshot

Comment: Have you tried committing your changes ? I get some weird green stuff in preview mode too.

Comment: Ah ok, that appears only on the preview mode, compiling it will show that normally, please add that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange formatting is coming from Github's preview mode. The green formatting is just a way to diff the new content (added by your update) and the old content of your markdown.